# How do I prevent the user from accessing the URL directly using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra

I'm new to Ruby and Sinatra and I was wondering how one could accomplish this. Can the redirect to method be used to verify if the user has come from a valid webpage?

For example:

```
get '/show' do
  erb :show 
  redirect '/otherpage' 
end



get '/otherpage' do
  flash[:message] = "How do I restrict access to this"
  erb :otherpage
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the request's `Referer` header, but it's not very reliable since request headers can be spoofed:

```
get 'show' do
  # Implement `allowed?` yourself
  redirect 'otherpage' if allowed? env['HTTP_REFERER']
  erb :show
end
```

You can add a signature in cookie to prevent the `Referer` header being spoofed.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
What are your views in checking to referer in the page I want to redirect to?
I implemented a version that checked for status again in my model in the otherpage block and redirected if the status was invalid. Would using cookies be a more appropriate solution?